# How to list all Quartz Schedulers?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to get the list of All JdbcJobStore schedulers in a DB and RAM Schedulers which are used in the current application.

Comment: You can get all Schedulers from the SchedulerFactory(http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/SchedulerFactory.html). So the Question is how do you instantiate your SchedulerFactoy/Factories?

Comment: the schedulerFactory depend on one quartz.propreties file, I do know this method but my problem is when I have multiple SchedulerFactory ( one for each quartz.properties file )

Comment: The `StandardQuartzSchedulerFactory` uses Property Files to configure the Schedulers. The `DirectSchedulerFactory` does not. So that's the reason why I'm asking how you instantiate your Schedulers. One way to get the Schedulers is to use the MBean(s) another one is to implement your own SchedulerListener and keep track of the instantiated Schedulers.

Comment: thx for answering,I instanciate the schedulers with StandardQuartzSchedulerFactory using property files.